# Can I have arrayList of string in realm object android

Tags: java, android, arraylist, realm, realm-list

As we dont have any list data type in realm, how can we use `ArrayList<String>` in a realm object?
I had same question for the arrayLists of the custom models we make i.e. `ArrayList<CustomModel>` but for that I understand that we first have to make RealmObject of same Custom model using

```
public class CustomObject extends RealmObject {
    private String name;
    private String age;
}
```

and then I can use

```
private RealmList<CustomObject> customObjectList;
```

in another RealmObject

Do i have to do same with arrayList of string?
1. Making String object
2. Use that object in Realm List

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Now it is possible to work with    RealmList     where T can be the following types: String, Integer, Boolean, Float, Double, Short, Long, Byte, byte[] and Date` (according to the official docs https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#relationships, see Relationships -> List of Primitives)

For example:

```
public RealmList<String> telephoneNumbers = new RealmList<>();
```

Comment: Very awaited feature (thumbsup)

Comment: What should be in schema.create ?

Comment: Hi @Salmaan would you please comment how to store list of string and how to retrieve back?

Answer (score 17):

Yes, you have to manually box your strings in a StringObject. We'd like to add support for `RealmList<String>`, `RealmList<Integer>`, etc., but it's a long way out.

Comment: That'd be great if you add that support. I'm about to use realm for the first time, I hope it works as I expect :)

Comment: You can follow progress on this feature here: https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/575

Comment: @Milanix that's a sad reason to downvote. Shame on you. The answer answers the question and is therefore useful. He is even honest in saying it will take a while before this will be supported.

Comment: @Milanix don't vote based on an an open issue or bug report, vote based on the *quality* of the answer.